# Is there a GUI framework available in anaconda (python )?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have been studying python and looking for ways to install and use some GUI framework I can use. I have read of native tkinter, and QtPy, Kivy, wxPython etc, but getting problems installing them.
Recently I read about Anaconda, and want to give it a try. But is it going to solve my issue for GUI framework ? I am seeing some frameworks in the list, however not sure, which one of them is GUI framework. Or is their no GUI framework included ( other than tkinter of course )

Comment: you shoud have `tkinter` installed with Python.

Comment: I know about tkinter, but I seems difficult to understand and use. Also, I am looking for application, that can help coding the GUI part using IDE, like visual studio does.

Comment: for many people `tkinter` is the easiest GUI :) If you need visual tool to create GUI then PyQt has Qt Designer, wxPython also have some tools. But pure code mostly is better to control then generated one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try libraries `traitsUI` and `Enaml`.  These are both supported in anaconda and both open-source projects from the company Enthought (many anaconda employees/founders are closely tied to Enthought).  These libraries make use of underlying backends (wx, qt, tk) and facilitate much faster GUI dev than does working with those core frameworks directly.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are some GUI frameworks in Anaconda. The list of included packages is [here](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs). Because you mentioned it specifically, pyqt is included.